# Center SKSpriteNode during pinch

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have implemented zoom/pinch on my SKScene with the selected answer in this thread:

[Zooming an SKNode inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461635/zooming-an-sknode-inconsistent?noredirect=1)

I am now attempting to get the hero character to stay centered (smoothly) during a pinch or zoom action because if I don't, the heroNode will disappear off the screen quickly.  I have a centerHero method which I can call when I want, and it works quite well, but when I call this method at the end of the pinch handler the effect is very, very jerky.  Here is the pinch handler:

```
- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
    [map runAction:[SKAction scaleBy:recognizer.scale duration:0]];
    recognizer.scale = 1;

    // While zooming/pinching, make sure hero is centered:
    [self centerHero];
}
```

and here is the center hero method:

```
- (void)centerHero
{
    CGFloat centerX = self.view.bounds.size.width/2;
    CGFloat centerY = self.view.bounds.size.height/2;

    CGFloat heroX = [self.heroNode parent].position.x;
    CGFloat heroY = [self.heroNode parent].position.y;

    CGPoint heroPoint = CGPointMake(heroX, heroY);
    CGPoint newHeroPoint = [self convertPoint:heroPoint fromNode:map];

    CGFloat newHeroX = newHeroPoint.x;
    CGFloat newHeroY = newHeroPoint.y;

    CGFloat xDiff = centerX - newHeroX;
    CGFloat yDiff = centerY - newHeroY;

    SKAction *moveBy = [SKAction moveByX:xDiff y:yDiff duration:5];
    [map runAction:moveBy];
}
```

Any suggestions on how to make this "auto-centering" smooth?

Comment: Why not make your hero a child of the map, then he'll scale and position relative with the map and you don't need to worry about reorienting him.

Comment: I am sorry, I was unclear.  The hero is a child of the map, and does scale and move with the map, but the problem is that as the map (and the hero) both grow larger, the hero, along with a great deal of the map, slides of the screen. Does that make sense?

Comment: Put another way: The scale does not change the position of the sprite _relative to the map_.  So as the map grows increasingly larger, and naturally less of it can fit on screen, the hero grows with it and if it is on a part of the map that slides off screen, then when the zoom is finished the user needs to move the map around to find the hero again.  What I would like is for the hero sprite to be the focal point of the zoom so that the hero is always on screen. Does this make sense?

Comment: Is your map made up of one big texture ? Or is it a collection of tiles or something of that nature ?

Comment: It is a collection of tiles. And the hero moves 32 pixels at a time in any direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you are scaling the map node, rather than the scene itself. When you scale the node, it will zoom to the *anchor point* of that node, instead of simply zooming in to the centre of the visible area.

If you scale the scene itself it should scale everything properly, e.g.:

```
[self runAction:[SKAction scaleBy:recognizer.scale duration:0]];
```

Assuming you're running this action from within the SKScene. You could also try:

```
[map.scene runAction:[SKAction scaleBy:recognizer.scale duration:0]];
```

...which would also point to the parent scene the map belongs to.

Comment: Thanks for the proposed answer but i actually want the zoom to be applied to only the map. There are other sprite nodes which serve as overlays, also children of the scene which i do not wish to zoom. The target of the zoom should be only the map and its children. I wonder if i should set the focal point of the map node to the center of the hero node?  Ill give that a try later.